# virtual functions in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How to declare the virtual functions in Objective C.

```
virtual void A(int s);
```

How to declare the same in Objective C.

```
-(void)A:(int)s //normal declaration
```

Comment: All objective-C methods are virtual. Functions are construct from C language, those cannot be virtual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of a C++ pure-virtual function in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374677/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-c-pure-virtual-function-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Objective-c does not support virtual functions, or to say that another way - all functions in obj-c classes are virtual as method calls are determined in run-time.

If your subclass overrides method from superclass and you reference subclass instance using pointer to superclass then subclass method will get called:

```
@interface A{
}
-(void) someMethod;
@end

@interface B : A{
}
-(void) someMethod;
@end

...
A* obj = [[B alloc] init];
[obj someMethod]; // method implementation from B will be called
```